# Where does Magento 2 Make its REST Order Call

Tags: magento2, frontend, rest-api

I [recently discovered](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/140753872210/magento-2-order-placing-is-a-rest-request) that Magento 2's checkout flow does **not** place an order during the PHP page request.  Instead, an additional RESTFUL API request is made to the application to place the order.

Does anyone know **where** this REST request takes place in Magento 2's code?

Comment: Do you mean where on the client (browser) side is the code that posts it, or where on the PHP server side is it processed (i.e. `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::place()`)?

Comment: @Vinai I meant where the API request is made, not where its processed.   I wasn't sure if it happened on the frontend, or if the backend code made a CURL request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens in [Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js)

```
        return storage.post(
            serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(payload)
        ).done(
            function () {
                if (redirectOnSuccess) {
                    window.location.replace(url.build('checkout/onepage/success/'));
                }
            }
        )
```